# C# character counter when writing to new line

Tags: c#

Basically I'm trying to read a really big text file and when the charecters of the line reach X amount write to a new line, but I can't seem to get the character count to work.  Any help is appreciated!

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(betaFilePath,FileMode.Open))
    using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        while (!rdr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string betaFileLine = rdr.ReadLine();
            int stringline = 0;
            if (betaFileLine.Contains("þTEMP"))
            {
                //sb.AppendLine(@"C:\chawkster\workfiles\New Folder\GEL_ALL_PRODUCTS_CONCORD2.DAT");
                string checkline = betaFileLine.Length.ToString();
                foreach (string cl in checkline)
                {
                    stringline++;
                    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\chawkster\workfiles\New Folder\GEL_ALL_PRODUCTS_CONCORD3.DAT", cl);
                    if(stringline == 1200)
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\chawkster\workfiles\New Folder\GEL_ALL_PRODUCTS_CONCORD3.DAT","\n");
                        stringline = 0;
                    }
                }                           
            }
        }
```

Error:

```
foreach (string cl in checkline)
Error   1   Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a Regular Expression to split the input string into chunks of the desired amount of characters. Here's an example:

```
string input = File.ReadAllText(inputFilePath);
MatchCollection lines = Regex.Matches(input, ".{1200}", RegexOptions.Singleline); // matches any character including \n exactly 1200 times
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

foreach (Match line in lines)
{
    output.AppendLine(line.Value);
}

File.AppendAllText(outputFilePath, output.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you have `string checkline = betaFileLine.Length.ToString();` since that will just take the current line and give you the length which is a number in a string format.  Don't you want all the characters in the current line?  Not sure what you want the numeric length there.

Not really sure what you are doing exactly but try:

```
// Get the current line as an array of characters
char[] checkline = betaFileLine.ToCharArray();

// Iterate for each character add to you file?
foreach (char cl in checkline)
```

Comment: You could just do `foreach (char cl in betaFileLine)`, a string is already an IEnumerable<char>. But you're right, I'm also not sure what he is trying to do.

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich Yes I broke it up so he could see step by step what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

System.String implements an IEnumerable - you need to use the code

```
foreach (char cl in checkLine)
{
    ...
    File.AppendAllText(fileName, cl.ToString());
}
```

I'd also suggest you put it all into an in-memory stream or [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(VS.71).aspx) and persist it all to the file in one go, rather than writing each character to the FileStream separately.